# Как запустить программу awk с параметрами?

Tags: c#

Есть команда для `awk` на виндовс, которая удаляет дубликаты строк. Из cmd всё работает

```
awk "!_[$1]++" 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Делаю на c# - никак не реагирует

```
 var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = "awk.exe",
            Arguments = " \"!_[$1]++\" 1.txt > 2.txt" 
        }
};
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Не уверен, что поможет, но `> 2.txt` — это не параметры приложения, а штатные средства для перенаправления выходного потока в файл командной строки Windows, вам, скорее всего, надо задавать это в свойствах класса Process отдельно

Answer (score 1):

```
var proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/c awk.exe \"!_[$1]++\" 1.tmp > " + outputname.Text,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```